# partial input.value styling?

Tags: javascript, css

I have to following Code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/hy4gz61w/) – I have an HTML-input and a button. – When clicking on the button a function is being run, that changes the input.value to this text: `"Black Yellow"`.

I would like the word `Yellow` to be yellow. `color: yellow`

I found some stuff on stack overflow, but nothing that really worked for me and from what I've read, I think this might be a bit tricky, but I really need this to work, so I would very much welcome any sort of input! – Simon

HTML

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Run </button>
<input name="input1" id="myInput">
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelector("#myInput").value = "Black Yellow";
}
```

Comment: You can do it with two connected by border inputs , if you want to see how let me know

Comment: You can't style individual words in an input. What you could do is create a _fake_ input using a div with `contenteditable=true` and some styling. Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/bxynd4v7/18/ (Type a colour and hit tab/click out of element)

Comment: Dear @BarLevin, @Turnip, Thank you for your answers! I have a second fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/bvth35m8/ It's still very reduced, but it's more like, what I have on my website. – If you type in `question1?` you get an answer. / You confirm the input with the Enter key. – Can I use one of your approaches in combination with this? 

Answer (score 1):

It is not an easy task as someone else mentioned. I have done something similar in react but that is completely different from doing it in plain javascript.

Here is how you can create your own input field:

Javascript:

```
const input = {
    element: document.getElementById("input"),
    focusing: false,
    value: ""
} 

function checkTarget(e) {
    if (e.target !== input.element){
        input.focusing = false
        return
    }
    input.focusing = true
    console.log(input.focusing)
}

function handleKey(e) {
    if (e.isComposing || e.keyCode === 229 || !input.focusing) {
        return;
    }
    input.value += e.key
    input.element.innerText = input.value
}

function handleClick() {
    let texts = input.value.split(" ")
    let span1 = document.createElement("span")
    let span2 = document.createElement("span")
    span1.innerText = texts[0] + " "
    span2.innerText = texts[1]
    span2.style.color = "yellow"
    input.element.innerText = ""
    input.element.appendChild(span1)
    input.element.appendChild(span2)
}

document.addEventListener("click", checkTarget)
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button"onclick="handleClick()"> Run </button>
<div id="input">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border: #777 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Run this in your fillde and let me know if it works.

Of course, this will work if there are only 2 words present in the `"input"` field. For more words you will need to tweak this code.

What i had to do in react was - create a text area which shows each word in different color (rainbow input). So i created an array of all rainbow colors, created a rand function which chooses one of them and then I did a similar thing as i did here. I used `map` on the array i got from `split(" ")` and then returned a `span` with inline styling for the text color.  And finally rendered the entire junk in the div. That was the easy part. The editing was the hard part (handling delete, backspace, tab etc). Which is when I gave up and stole a component off of github.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I unfortunately don't quite understand all of that code, but do you think, that I could combine it with what I have here: jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/bvth35m8 (If you type in question1? you get an answer. / You confirm the input with the Enter key.)

Comment: I just read your edit, and I have to confess it kind of confused me. I'm unfortunately not very experienced with JS, but I know someone, who is a software developer. I will meet with him, as soon a possible and go of this with him, maybe than I understand it to a point where I can implement and change it to my needs, but again thank you!

Comment: Do you mind up-voting the answer? I spent 15 minutes writing all that code.

Comment: Yes you can deff. rework your code so that it works like you want it to. 
You do however need a bit of JS knowledge to understand and reuse my code though. 
I wont rewrite your fiddle an integrate the code i wrote here because then i'd basically be doing your job which isnt the goal of this website.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. I upvoted your answer. – I fully agree, I'm just still, very much, in the process of learning, so I'll have to spend some time with this. 

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task. You can't control the word color in HTML at the moment. You need to create your own input somehow using 2 input elements. For every color an input. But as I said, it can get complicated.

```js
function renderFakeInput(input, colors) {
  input.style.display = "none";

  const fakeInput = document.createElement("div");
  fakeInput.classList.add("fake-input");
  fakeInput.addEventListener("click", () => renderRealInput(input, colors, fakeInput));

  for (const color of colors) {
    const word = document.createElement("div");
    word.textContent = color;
    word.style.color = color;
    fakeInput.appendChild(word);
  }
  input.parentElement.appendChild(fakeInput);
}

function renderRealInput(input, colors, fakeInput) {
  const onBlur = () => {
    input.removeEventListener("blur", onBlur);
    renderFakeInput(input, input.value.split(" "));
  };

  input.style.display = "";
  input.value = colors.join(" ");
  input.focus();
  input.addEventListener("blur", onBlur);
  fakeInput.remove();
}

const colorString = "Black Yellow";
const colors = colorString.split(" ");

const inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("multi-color"));
for (const input of inputs) {
  renderFakeInput(input, colors);
}
```

```css
.fake-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="multi-color" />
</div>
<div>
  <input class="multi-color" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! This is just a small part of a bigger project and I'm doing various different things with this one input that I have, so I think I really can't just add another one… Is there maybe any way, that I can achieve this inside of one input? – I unfortunately also don't have a lot of JS experience, but I'm very willing to learn, so if you have any links to articles, or anything… I thought maybe I can get some sort of tag inside of the value, like `<b>` and then just tell the browser that every `<b>` inside of the `input`, or `value` is yellow… 

Comment: Or maybe I can tell the browser to temporarily change the innerHTML of the input and write something into it like that… Just trying to brainstorm an idea. 

Comment: What about you display a colored fake input (using styled divs) and then if you click on the divs you switch to an input field that displays the (colorless) values. After the Blur event, you switch back the the styled divs.

Comment: Can you maybe do fiddle? I don't quite understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: This: https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/bvth35m8/  is more like, what I have on my website. When you type in `question1?` you get an answer…

Comment: I added a quick implementation of what I mean.